# Accessing twitter stream api with TwitterKit

Tags: ios, twitter-streaming-api

I am using twitter's Fabric platform to post tweets to twitter. In fabric there is TwitterKit framework that manages the auth and other stuff. Now I need to access twitter streaming api. How can use this authentication info already established by twitter with streaming api.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSURLConnection`.

```
    func connectUserStream() {
        let twtrRequest = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json", parameters: nil, error: nil)
        let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: twtrRequest, delegate: self)
        urlConnection?.start()
    }

    // MARK: NSURLConnectionDelegate
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        let response: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        println(response)
    }
```

Comment: Although not always required from the point of view of the answerer, it is preferable to add some explanation to your code